# Velocity imparted by twist.linear

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am publishing twist.linear.x = 0.5 on cmd_vel topic within the callback function of /pose topic. Whenever pose in x direction of my bot is less than goal x component I publish the twist command. For the /pose callback I am using rosspin with a ros::rate of 0.5 hz (ie 1 time in 2 seconds). Does it mean that 0.5 m/s will be imparted to my bot until the next iteration of /pose callback continuously or it will impart 0.5 for an instant and my bot will be still and wait for next iteration?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268781/velocity-imparted-by-twist.linear/) by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A simple controller might receive a single cmd_vel and then try to maintain that velocity forever, a more safety minded one could be set to maintain it for a few seconds then come to a stop if no other cmd_vel messages are received.  It's possible at your low update rate the 0.5 m/s will decay a bit then bump back up to commanded speed when the next update arrives.

If you add more details on the node you have subscribing to cmd_vel the exact answer could be determined.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0